# How to put a Div inside an if statement

Tags: php

Hi i have a code that displays title, date and location. I want it to put on a div, unfortunately there is some wrong in my code and it loops my div.

I just want all may data to be inside "may-container" i just don't know how to create this container.

Hope you could help me with this. Thanks

```
<div class="may-container">
 <div class="May">
 title
 date 
 location
 </div>

 <div class="May">
 title
 date 
 location
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```html
$counter = 0;
while ( $startdate <= $enddate) {
    
    if ( date("F",strtotime($result['date'])) == "May" && date("m, Y",strtotime($result['date'])) >= date("m, Y") )
    {
     if ($counter < 1)
 {
  echo "<div class='May-container'>";
  $counter++;
 }
  echo "<div class= 'May'>";
  echo $result['title'],"<br>";
  echo date ('F \ j,\ Y',strtotime($result['date']) ), "<br>";
  echo $result['location'];
     echo "</div>";     
    }
    
  

   $startdate = strtotime("+120 day", $startdate);
}
```

Comment: It loops your `div`, because your `if()` is in a loop `while ( $startdate <= $enddate)`. So it looks like you have at least 2 `$result['date']` in `May`. So what is your desired outcome than?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 1):

if your code `date("F",strtotime($result['date']))` produces a month in words then why do you have to put if and else?

why not:

```
while ( $startdate <= $enddate) {
  echo "<div class='" . date('F',strtotime($result['date'])) . "'>";
  echo $result['title'],"<br>";
  echo date ('F \ j,\ Y',strtotime($result['date']) ), "<br>";
  echo $result['location'];
  echo "</div>";

  $startdate = strtotime("+120 day", $startdate);
}
```

**EDIT:** to answer your comment, you can try this code:

> This code is only applicable if your Data is sorted out by date

```
$last_month = '';
$is_first = true;
while ( $startdate <= $enddate) {

  if($last_month != date('F',strtotime($result['date']))){
     echo '</div>';
     $is_first = true;
  }

  if($is_first){
     $last_month = date('F',strtotime($result['date']));
     echo "<div class='". strtolower($last_month) . "-container'>";
     $is_first = false;
  }
  echo "<div class='" . date('F',strtotime($result['date'])) . "'>";
  echo $result['title'],"<br>";
  echo date ('F \ j,\ Y',strtotime($result['date']) ), "<br>";
  echo $result['location'];
  echo "</div>";

  $startdate = strtotime("+120 day", $startdate);
}
```

if the code above code runs as what i expected(sorry i didnt run it for i dont have enough time to) it will yields something like:

```
<div class="may-container">
  <div class="May">
    title
    date 
    location
  </div>

  <div class="May">
    title
    date 
    location
  </div>
</div>

<div class="june-container">
  <div class="June">
    title
    date 
    location
  </div>

  <div class="June">
    title
    date 
    location
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi cee.. i put if and else for some trappings. my one lacking is just to put a parent container for all the may data. tnx

Comment: @shadowbudz check my edit, incase you use it and yields error, advance sorry for i didnt compile/run it, dont have enough time, but hope you can get idea from it